Who picks up when you call the "phone number for you" following a possible pilot deviation?
Related - What should you do when ATC gives you a number to call to discuss a violation?
As a pilot, whom might you expect to be speaking to on calling the telephone number provided by ATC? Is it ATC themselves or do they file a report for the issue to be dealt with elsewhere?
It does seems surprising that they aren't telling you to expect to be contacted, if it's deemed an important safety issue.

In most cases the number ATC gives you will be for the recorded telephone line into the operational area—likely the supervisor's desk. If they say "possible pilot deviation" it is almost certainly going to be that recorded line. Probably they have already started filling out a Mandatory Occurrence Report for whatever situation prompted the Brasher warning in the first place.
When you call you will likely talk to the supervisor on duty, who may well be a different person than anyone who was working at the time of the incident. They will take down your name, pilot number, and a callback phone number and add them to the MOR. Eventually the FSDO will get the paperwork and an Aviation Safety Inspector at the FSDO will call you back.
In theory all that should happen when you call ATC is you give your information and they write it down and say "Thanks, you might get a call from the FSDO in a few weeks." But it's possible ATC might try get into more of a discussion about what happened. It's probably best for you to politely avoid engaging; keep in mind that the call is being recorded.
It's also possible ATC might give you the non-recorded telephone number if they just want to have a discussion about something without making it a big deal. If they say the phrase "possible pilot deviation" it's almost guaranteed to be recorded; if they don't say that phrase it might not be, but unfortunately you don't really have a way of knowing unless you ask.
Remember that you should always file an ASRS report if anything safety- or compliance-related occurred. That's the point of the "possible pilot deviation" phraseology: to inform you that ATC thinks something happened and that you should probably make a note of it so you can tell your side of the story later.
If you're interested in reading about what kinds of things are mandatory reports for ATC, they're listed in Appendix A of FAA JO 7210.632.

At Denver Center, we'll give you the number for the Operations Manager, who has the front desk in the control room. Our crew supervisors answer to them.
By the time you call, they will have looked over the situation and spoken with the controller and the crew supervisor, and will have a thorough understanding of what happened, from the ATC side.
They're not out to get you, they just want your input on what happened. Often, if it's an issue of misunderstanding, that'll be the end of it.

Air Traffic Control is who you are calling.  They are gathering more information about what might have occurred and a phone call is an easy way to do that.
Realize that first-off you are likely busy at the time, flying an airplane, so they don't want to have a discussion right then (except to correct an immediate safety situation ie "go around").  Second, they probably don't know WHO to call and might not know where you are going or when you will be available.  (They initially just know that you are Cessna-123 etc).  They could start pulling records (aircraft registration, flight plan, aircraft rental agreement, other ATC tapes....) but they often start by trying to have a conversation, then determine next steps.
